# DRF JWT Authentication object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm using a library [suggested by DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#json-web-token-authentication) ([djangorestframework_simplejwt](https://github.com/SimpleJWT/django-rest-framework-simplejwt)), installed using

```
pip install djangorestframework_simplejwt
```

Added it to settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

Created two endpoints from imported views

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView, TokenRefreshView

urlpatterns = [
    # JWT Token
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain'),
    # get a new token before the old expires.
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view, name='token_refresh'),
]
```

The users are being created without any problem in the database and the passwords are being hashed.

If i go to http://localhost:8000/api/token/, then get the following view

[image: Token Obtain Pair JWT DRF]

Posting the correct user with its password and then I get the following error

[image: AttributeError at /api/token/]

> [17/Apr/2020 12:06:51] "POST /api/token/ HTTP/1.1" 500 122221 Internal
>   Server Error: /api/token/ Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\letsgo\authenticationJwt\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py",
>   line 34, in inner
>       response = get_response(request)   File "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\letsgo\authenticationJwt\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
>   line 115, in _get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\letsgo\authenticationJwt\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
>   line 113, in _get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\letsgo\authenticationJwt\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py",
>   line 54, in wrapped_view
>       return view_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\letsgo\authenticationJwt\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py",
>   line 71, in view
>       return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\letsgo\authenticationJwt\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py",
>   line 505, in dispatch
>       response = self.handle_exception(exc)   File "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\letsgo\authenticationJwt\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py",
>   line 465, in handle_exception
>       self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)   File "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\letsgo\authenticationJwt\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py",
>   line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
>       raise exc   File "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\letsgo\authenticationJwt\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py",
>   line 502, in dispatch
>       response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\letsgo\authenticationJwt\lib\site-packages\rest_framework_simplejwt\views.py",
>   line 27, in post
>       serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)   File "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\letsgo\authenticationJwt\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py",
>   line 234, in is_valid
>       self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)   File
>   "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\letsgo\authenticationJwt\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py",
>   line 436, in run_validation
>       value = self.validate(value)   File "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\letsgo\authenticationJwt\lib\site-packages\rest_framework_simplejwt\serializers.py",
>   line 73, in validate
>       refresh = self.get_token(self.user)   File "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\letsgo\authenticationJwt\lib\site-packages\rest_framework_simplejwt\serializers.py",
>   line 68, in get_token
>       return RefreshToken.for_user(user)   File "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\letsgo\authenticationJwt\lib\site-packages\rest_framework_simplejwt\tokens.py",
>   line 161, in for_user
>       user_id = getattr(user, api_settings.USER_ID_FIELD) AttributeError: 'MyUser' object has no attribute 'id'

The error is clear, MyUser object doesn't have attribute id. Instead, it has `user_id` as a primary_key, as you can see next

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='userId')
    password = models.CharField(db_column='userPassword', max_length=256)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=100, unique=True)
```

Thing is, I don't want to be changing the current MyUser fields.

---

### EDIT

Going to the [settings of djangorestframework_simplejwt](https://github.com/SimpleJWT/django-rest-framework-simplejwt/blob/master/rest_framework_simplejwt/settings.py) it's possible to read

```
DEFAULTS = {
    ...
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    ...
}
```

So, considering I don't want to change MyUser primary_key to id, I've gone to the place djangorestframework_simplejwt was installed and searched where USER_ID_FIELD is being declared.

Only found it in venv\Jwt\Lib\site-packages\djangorestframework_simplejwt-4.4.0.dist-info\METADATA, in SIMPLE_JWT. There, changed to

```
  SIMPLE_JWT = {
      ...
      'USER_ID_FIELD': 'user_id',
      ...
  }
```

Then, restarted the venv and runserver. The problem still happens.

Comment: Great Job it worked bruh

Comment: @Mukul did you read the answer to this question?

Comment: yeah you had put that below but one problem I am facing here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've reset the changes done in METADATA, then gone to my project settings.py file and added

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'user_id'
}
```